# How to create buttons with different value using for loop

Tags: javascript

So this is my code.
I want to create buttons like

Random 1
Random 2
....
...
Random 10

Is there any way I can reach it with for loop in JavaScript?
And so is id, like the first button's id is "button1" ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  var i = 0;
  var x = new Array(11);
  var y = new Array(11);
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
  x[i] = 35.38825899+Math.random()*0.007962;
  y[i] = 0.03903201/0.007962*x;
  document.write('<input type="button" value="Random" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
  }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: What you have done is right. What is the problem?

Comment: All the buttons have the same value, I want to make buttons' values as Random1 Random2 ..... Random9 Random10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Change the:

```
value="Random"
```

To:

```
value="Random ' + i + '"
```

**Final Code**

```
document.write('<input type="button" id="button'+i+'" value="Random'+i+'" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<input type="button" value="Random" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```

to

```
document.write('<input type="button" id="button' + i + 'value="Random' + i + '" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```

---

Or with jQuery

```
var button = $("<input>").attr("type", "button").attr("id", "button" + i).val("Random" + i).click(sfcshonan)

$(document).append(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   document.write('<input type="button" id="button'+i+'" value="Random'+i+'" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```

Insted of

```
   document.write('<input type="button" value="Random" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<input type="button" value="Random '+i+'" onclick="sfcshonan()"/>'+'<br />');
```