# add dialogs to uploaded photos and store unique value in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a little issue, I'm developing web app where you can upload some photos, then I store metadates about photos in my DB and I generate a unique primary key to every photo as a "pointer" to my DB. Then I'm appending to photos dialog button, where you can modify metadates stored in DB. But my problem is, that I want to store in every button unique primary key value for photo. But when I upload 3 photos, I have 3 buttons and they all have a primary key set to the last photo uploaded. So I cannot modify first or second photo in DB.
Don't you have any advice or example how to solve my problem, please?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Amitesh code is kind of long so I made something like "simulation" - create button simulates uploaded photos so with click I generate dialog button where I'm trying to store my ID value( PK to DB ) - fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/7rr85xuw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code , it looking good only one fault is that , you are generating button like this :

```
<button id="change_coord">Change coordinates</button>
<button id="change_coord">Change coordinates</button>
<button id="change_coord">Change coordinates</button>
```

That is having save id , so try to give them different it. so,it will have different values, now  it will only store last inserted value.

Read this links it will help you

[LInk1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580509/how-to-create-buttons-with-different-value-using-for-loop)

[LInk2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583678/creating-multiple-button-using-while-loop-but-only-first-button-is-responsive-wh)

read this link it will

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Like generate them with different id? This id="change_coord" should be different for all buttons? But how can I do that?

Comment: Looks great, thak you!

Comment: Sorry but another problem, when I generate buttons with different IDs I cannot use this: $(document).on("click", "#change_coord", function()
{
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
});